# Need to apply a clear function or rest for the following code to rest the input field

Tags: javascript, python, django

I need to apply a clear function when I add the input frequency. Now when I add a number say 2, 2 fields are created and when I add 3, it's getting appended and showing 5 fields. I need the exact number of fields as given in the input. Please give any tips

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                {%csrf_token%}

<div class="mb-3">
    <label>{{medicineform.frequency.label}}</label>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
        {{medicineform.frequency}}
    </div>
<br>
<div id="dynamicCheck">
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="createNewElement();"/>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div id="newElementId">Your time here</div>

<br>
<div class="mb-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add a reminder</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
        <div class="col-4"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#medicine").autocomplete({
            source: '{% url 'autocomplete' %}',
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
 function createNewElement() {
    var inpObj = document.getElementById("id_frequency").value;
     // First create a DIV element.
     var i;
     for (i=1;i<=inpObj;i++)
     {
            var txtNewInputBox = document.createElement('div');
     // Then add the content (a new input box) of the element

            txtNewInputBox.innerHTML = "<input type='time' name='reminder' id='newInputBox'>";
     // Finally put it where it is supposed to appear.
            document.getElementById("newElementId").appendChild(txtNewInputBox);


     }
 }
 </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear everything inside the container in the beginning of `createNewElement()` function so that it doesn't have any of the previous child. Use the following code to do that

```
function createNewElement() {
    document.getElementById("newElementId").innerHTML = ''
    // Do the rest of the things
}
```